# Counting the frequency of each word in a dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[image]I have the following sample dataframe. It contains information about each user, with his reviews split into words (separated by commas) and the number of words in each review

I wanted to group the data using the frequency of words in ['tokens'] for each user such that i can have the following result

[image]

I used the following code 
`count = user_tokens_aggregated.groupby(['username','tokens']).count() 
print(count)`

But it should me the following result, as if it was handling each review as ONE PIECE (hence the result = 1 for all rows) rather than each review as consisting of a number of words

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for new `DataFrame` and then aggregate by [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'tokens':['hotel, night','hotel','hotel'],
         'username':list('aab')
})

df = (df.set_index('username')['tokens']
       .str.split(',', expand=True)
       .stack()
       .rename('username')
       .reset_index(name='tokens'))
print (df)
  username  level_1  tokens
0        a        0   hotel
1        a        1   night
2        a        0   hotel
3        b        0   hotel

count = df.groupby(['username','tokens']).size().reset_index(name='token_count')
print (count)
  username  tokens  token_count
0        a   night            1
1        a   hotel            2
2        b   hotel            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your result is expected, because the column contains only **one string** (of several words). What you want to do is split this string into a list:

```
In [4]: s = "this, is, a, long, string, of, words"                              

In [5]: s.split(', ')                                                           
Out[5]: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'long', 'string', 'of', 'words']
```